# How can i get the location of coords in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, localization

A my friend and are doing little resarches and tests over the google maps API, we are trying to retrieve the Localization (City) from a given coords.

We have been able to show on the map that coords, but it doesnt explicity tells us the city or information over the place.

Hope you can give us a hand because we have not found any way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for bothering here, we finally found it out:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

> What is Geocoding?
>
> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers or position the map.
>
> Reverse geocoding is the process of converting geographic coordinates
>   into a human-readable address

This description says exactly the oposite we were looking for, but there are functions to do it the other way.
Hope this help others who may have the same doubt.

Answer (score 0):

hi hope this tool will be helpful 
http://www.google.co.in/enterprise/mapsearth/products/coordinate.html
Google Maps Coordinate is a workforce management tool that improves the efficiency of your mobile team.

Comment: Im not sure how this tool/application can help me out to get to what city/country belongs some coords